# How to maintain header height more than 300px in every page of html print.....?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
@page { 
   @top-center{
       content: "Header text goes here"; 
   }
}
div#printhead {
position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 20em;
padding-bottom: 1em;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media screen {
  div#printhead {
  }
  div#docbody {
  margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media print {
  div#printhead {
  display: block;
  }
  div#docbody {
  margin-top: 3em;
  }
}
</style>
```

I want to set a Bigger Header in my Print Page and the content is dynamically came form database.
I cant increase the header height more than 250px.
How do I increase the Header height to more than 300px?

Comment: There are quite some issues with your question, first of all this doesn't really have anything to do with Windows, and your question is not really clear. Please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There is a property that might help you.

min-height: 300px

Comment: That header must be repeated in every page of my print.

Comment: if i include min-height content is overlapped

Comment: Could you add some html of your page?

Comment: By the way, If your content is overlapped, it might be because you set your header to fixed, which is normal. To do so you should add a margin-top: 300px to your content. But do you really need to set a fixed header?

Comment: if i add margin-top:300px in every page of my print it is effected...!!!